# Parse text file with two 'space' delimiters

Tags: python, parsing

I am trying to read this text file in a list of tuples or a `numpy` array of tuples `(x, y)` like:

```
[[0,1], [2,3], [4,5], [2,1], [4,2]]
```

My text file is:

```
6
0 1
2 3  4 5  2 1
4 2
```

I have used this function to separate :

```
l = 'tiny.txt'
arr = []

def readDatFile(l):
    
    fh = open(eval('l'), 'r+')

    for i in range(0,14):
        arr.append([])
        lines = fh.readline()
        edge = lines.strip().split("  ")
        for parts in edge:
            arr_split = lines.split(" ")
            arr.append(x_y_split[i])
            
        
    return arr

readDatFile(l)
```

I could figure something out if I knew how the indexing worked after a split applied. Or if given some pointers.

*I know the first line is to be omitted too but now want to omit the first line but now I want to know how to parse this file*

Comment: What is `eval('l')` supposed to be doing? Why not just `l`? Also, why not use a more descriptive name?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Good question! This part of the code is part of a bigger program. I copy-pasted it from my IDE. Essentially there is a function above all of that asking for input (As which txt file to parse)

Comment: I will work on my "use a more descriptive name" next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the third parameter of the `range()` function, the `step`:

```
t = []

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        l = list(map(int, l.split()))
        for i in range(0, len(l)-1, 2):
            t.append([l[i], l[i+1]])

print(t)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [2, 1], [4, 2]]
```

---

Breaking it down:

1. Define a list to store the sublists:

```
t = []
```

2. Open the specified file in read mode:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
```

3. Iterate through the file's lines:

```
for l in f:
```

4. Use the built-in [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) method to convert each line into a list of integers:

```
l = list(map(int, l.split()))
```

5. `range(0, len(l))` is the equivalent of just `range(len(l))`, but if you want to use the `step` argument without having to include the name of the [keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html), you'll need to add in the `0`:

```
for i in range(0, len(l)-1, 2):
```

6. Use the slices `[i]` and `[i+1]` and append the sublists to the `t` list defined in the top of the code:

```
t.append([l[i], l[i+1]])
```